# Difficulty in understanding in datepickerdialog 2nd one parameters

Tags: android

Someone can explain me what is the following 2nd parameter tries to explain. I have look around stackoverflow. I haven't got satisfactory explanation. It would be appriciated if anyone can help me to understand. Thanks in advance. My following code is not working.

```
private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = null;
    datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,datepickerdialog.OnDateSetListener(MainActivity.this),day,month,year);
    datepickerdialog.show();
}
```

Comment: its a interface. Your mainactivity needs to implement that interface. A callback when date is set

Comment: Friend please could you explain me. I am not able to get what you mean to say. Thanks for the response.

Comment: `OnDateSetListener` is a interface. You need to have this interface implemented in `MainActivity.java` and implement method `onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)`. You can update ui once you pick the date in onDateSet

Comment: What does second parameter try to explain in  DatePickerDialog. Please, could you explain me little bit in detail thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a [java `interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) which will be used as a callback when date is set in your dialog.

here MainActivity class will be implementing interface `OnDateSetListener` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDateSetListener {
.
.
.
.
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       //do your work once date is set
  }
.
.
.
}
```

once user sets a date, onDateSet callback method from implemented interface `OnDateSetListener` will be called, and you can perform your desired operation in this function.

Comment: so what is new DatePickerDialog with few parameter. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @J.Vyas what do you mean by "DatePickerDialog with few parameter" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) for understand what is the second parameter.

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) to for more example in Java code.

Example of use :

```
fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // Here, do what you want when date is set
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

You can to pass "null" as second parameter if you don't want do something when date is set.